# dataset from excel to latex using https://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables#

Tags: dataset, latex, pdflatex, overleaf

I have a big dataset in excel which I would like to copy to a latex document. I've tried it using https://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables#. Unfortunately, when I tried to paste the latex-version of the dataset into latex (online version), I got a message telling me that I should upload a file directly to latex instead because direct copying from copyboard to latex doesn't work.
Do you have any suggestions how to deal with it? Is it somehow possible to export the  output from https://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables# into a file that latex can read?

Many thanks in advance for your support.

Best,

Comment: Stay away from these online table generators. They produce the ugliest code ever seen by mankind and produce a lot of problems by all these incorrect `\multicolumn` they insert, which will destroy all attempts for a good alignment. Instead have a look at packages like `csvsimple`, they can automatically include the tables exported by excel.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.